# How do you fix Xcode 14 warning: NavigationLink presenting a value must appear inside a NavigationContent-based NavigationView. Link will be disabled

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, ios16, xcode14

Since installing Xcode 14, I am now getting the following error message printed in my console:

> NavigationLink presenting a value must appear inside a
> NavigationContent-based NavigationView. Link will be disabled.

My app is structured as follows:

1. I have View A wrapped in a NavigationView. The Navigation View has a navigation link inside it that links to View B.
2. I have View B that doesn't have a Navigation View, but has a navigation link to View C. View B inherits the navigation view defined in View A

The warning is printed when I press the back button on View B, popping back to View A.
The warning goes away when I wrap View B in a NavigationView, but this of course now displays View B in two Navigation Views, which is not what I want.

I'm unsure why this warning is printing, because View B inherits the NavigationView defined in View A.

Comment: Without including a [mre], it is unlikely that this is going to be debuggable from just a description.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. Adding a check for iOS16 and using the new navigationstack if true fixed it for me.

```swift
WindowGroup {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        NavigationStack {
            ContentView()
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try to add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to the `NavigationView`. It helps in my case.

```swift
NavigationView {
    // View A
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

Answer (score 1):

Will be deprecated in ios16,
The official documentation link is provided here, you can view the specific details

> Deprecated
>
> Use NavigationStack and NavigationSplitView instead. For more
> information, see Migrating to new navigation types.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview

Comment: You should quote the essential parts of the  documentation and leave the link for reference. See [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't incredibly intelligent, but it's clever enough to rectify Apple's user-unfriendly modifications.

```
struct SmartNavigationView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            NavigationStack(root: content)
        } else {
            NavigationView(content: content)
                .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var body: some View {
    SmartNavigationView {
        NavigationLink {
            Text("Perhaps it's because they lack faith in using SwiftUI for serious projects.")
        } label: {
            Text("Why did SwiftUI developers implement these types of changes?")
        }
    }
}
```